# Does anybody know any HTTP server that works over UDP?

Tags: http, udp

I am trying to build a peer-2-peer network over http. This network needs to employ UDP due to connectivity and energy consumption issues. I know this isn't conventional.

My question is: does anybody know any open source http server that runs over UDP. Preferably
written in Java?

As far as my own searching goes, i have found this http://nodejs.org/ , but i am searching for alternatives.

Thanks,
Cezar

Comment: There's nothing at the page you linked about UDP.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so any such server is avaialble.

As from the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

> HTTP communication usually takes place over TCP/IP connections. The
>   default port is TCP 80, but other ports can be used. This does not
>   preclude HTTP from being implemented on top of any other protocol on
>   the Internet, or on other networks. HTTP only presumes a reliable
>   transport; any protocol that provides such guarantees can be used; the
>   mapping of the HTTP/1.1 request and response structures onto the
>   transport data units of the protocol in question is outside the scope
>   of this specification.

Comment: Yeah. The _reliable transport_ part is rather clear in excluding UDP IMHO

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo:- Yes that is probably the reason!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into this work  ... http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/Courses/Computer-Networks-Lab/projects/spring2000/http_udp/index.htm

Comment: "You don't have permission to access /Courses/Computer-Networks-Lab/projects/spring2000/http_udp/index.htm on this server."